# SQL Server: error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types, casting

I have read many articles and tried several methods but don't have any luck.

I am importing table A (whose cost is `char` to table B (which requires `float`).

What I tried:

```
 --cast([Cost]   as float)
 -- cast(ISNULL([Cost],0)   as float)
 -- NULLIF(CAST(ISNULL([Cost],0)   as float), 0)
 convert(float,replace([Cost],',','') )[Cost]
```

Sample data

```
FINAL Freight Cost
1248
1248
193.79
201.56
1475.71
97.86
97.86
97.86
125.49
97.86
447.83
450
492.99
450
```

And I still get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Update:

In addition, I am not sure how to modify the existing code based on the answers;

The existing code structure

```
1. creat table B
2. insert into B () select[DestAddress], [COST] from A
```

I also tried `CAST(test AS FLOAT) AS CastedValue`

---

Why `float`? The dataset will be sent to an optimization algorithm which requires `float`. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Try without replacing the dots?

Comment: Replace [FINAL Freight Cost] with LTRIM(RTRIM([FINAL Freight Cost]))

Comment: What are you trying to do in your own words?

Comment: what about : select convert(float,'492.99')

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader This works, but not sure how to modify for my code.

Comment: You're trying to **import** data? how? what is the source?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yes, from table A to table B. Table A is from ms access.

Comment: Thanks. How is the Access column defined? what is the import method? openrowset?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I think all of the columns are `short text`. Import wizard.

Comment: Slight detour...you are importing this to a column named Cost. That is an indication that you want a precise number. Float is a poor choice for a datatype for this column. You should use an exact datatype like numeric or decimal instead.

Comment: Silly question: As your `insert into B()` does not provide column names it might be, that you try to insert the address to cost and vice versa...

Comment: @Shnugo That's only a structure. The real code has necessary column names.

Comment: @JohnHass, It is good to reduce the code to the needed parts. We see many quesitons here on SO full of irrelevant code. But you are exaggerating this principle... :-) ... It leads other people onto wrong tracks...

Comment: My guess is that you have a row in your source that has some value that is not actually a valid number. This is so often the case when people store numbers as characters.

Comment: John Hass, try to check your source with `ISNUMERIC`. With a SQL-Server 2012+ you might use `TRY_CAST` and examine rows returning with `NULL`

Comment: @Shnugo Tried. There is a "n/a" in 100k rows. Solved. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(test NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('1248')
,('1248')
,('193.79')
,('201.56')
,('1475.71')
,('97.86')
,('97.86')
,('97.86')
,('125.49')
,('97.86')
,('447.83')
,('450')
,('492.99')
,('450');

SELECT *
     ,CAST(test AS FLOAT) AS CastedValue
FROM @tbl;
```

But the main question is: Why?

#### Hint 1: Float is the wrong type for this!

From the column name I take, that you are dealing with *costs*. The `FLOAT` type is absolutely to be avoided here! You should use `DECIMAL` or specialised types to cover money or currency values...

#### Hint 2: NVarchar is the wrong type for this!

And the next question is again: Why? Why are these values stored as `NVARCHAR`? If ever possible you should solve your problem here...

### UPDATE

You edited your question and added this

```
insert into B () select[DestAddress], [COST]
```

I do not know the target table's column names, but this should work

```
INSERT INTO B(ColumnForAddress,ColumnForCost)
SELECT CAST([COST] AS FLOAT),[DestAddress] FROM YourSourceTable
```

### UPDATE 2

After all your comments I'm pretty sure, that there are invalid values within your numbers list. Use `ISNUMERIC` or - if you are using SQL-Server-2012+ even better `TRY_CAST` to find invalid values.

Comment: This has to be stored as `float`, since it will be send into an optimization algorithm. The database is stored by someone else.

Comment: So where is your actual problem? All provided numbers seem to cast correctly?

Comment: Your code is working, but I am not sure how to modify it for the existing code. The existing code 1.creat a table 2. `insert into xxx() select * from`.

Comment: I am importing database A to database B (which requires `float`), and failed because the type conversion problem.

Comment: @JohnHass This is something you should have mentioned in your question. Please add the relevant code... It should be as easy as `INSERT INTO tbl(TargetColumn, OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2) SELECT CAST(SourcColumn AS FLOAT),OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2 FROM SourcTable`. There are probably more columns, the simple asterisk `*` is tricky...

Comment: Thanks. Updated. I know it is easy, but it just cannot return the right results.

Comment: Then, it is equivalent to what I have tried at the beginning. Thanks! I mentioned `cast([Cost]   as float)` at the top line.

Comment: @JohnHass, if this does not work, your problem is somewhere else: 1) invalid values, 2) empty strings, 3) wrong column mapping, 4) a trigger you do not think of, 5) a constraint you do not think of, 6) many more... Just try to think with my head. I got nothing else than a few lines you provided in the beginning. You know what you've done, I did not even know about an `INSERT` statement... [Try to set up a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JohnHass, Please see my update 2. If this solves your issue it would be kind to accept my answer and vote it up (if not done yet). Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert` function , it works smoothly even adding spaces , so there is no need for using `Ltrim` or `Rtrim`!

Example:

```
select convert(float,' 492.99    ') + 1 as converted
```

Result:

```
Converted
---------
493.99
```

Comment: I actually tried `convert(float,replace([Cost],',','') )[Cost]`

Answer (score -1):

```sql
FORMAT(ROUND(cast(Total as float), 2), 'C') AS GrandTotal
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.